# can we actually align an iframe into middle of a website?. It di'nt work for me. Can anyone give me a solution for this?

Tags: html

I am trying to align my frame into center of my website, which doesn't seem to work with the align attribute. Does anyone have a better idea. Here is my following fragment of code.

```
<iframe id="9MS89fgJMj"   width="600"  height="350" align="middle" margin:0px;border-width:0px;overflow:hidden;"  scrolling="no" src="http://www.embeddedanalytics.com/reports/displayreport?reportcode=9MS89fgJMj&chckcode=gaqMuciIGQGzvVXXQQJfxM"   title="Google Analytics Dashboard"></iframe>
```

Comment: Seems like your quotes are somehow misplaced in your code.

Comment: I think there's nothing wrong with quotes. Right align and left align seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use css, first with margin, 2nd with transform, 3rd with negative margin. Target your iframe instead of the classes I listed:

```
//this should work everywhere, but depending on you page structure might not
iframe{
    margin: 0 auto;
}

//this is not ie8 friendly or older versions of ff/chrome etc
iframe{
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

//this is IE8 friendly, but requires a hardcoded margin that is half the width
iframe{
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -300px;
}
```

Comment: Can you also add the <iframe> to the above mentioned answer?

Comment: Updated answer, just throw that in a <style> somewhere and depending on what browsers you need to support give each one a try!

Comment: Great buddy. It's the second time on the same day you helped me out. Thanks.

Comment: Awesome, I'm on a roll today! Glad I could help out